# How to make XFCE reserve space for panel on the right monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xubuntu, xfce-panel

I'm using Xubuntu 13.04 on my laptop that has an external screen attached. The big external monitor also has a vertical panel. My external screen is on the right side of my laptop.

When I maximize windows on my external monitor, the panel overlaps those. However, when I maximize windows on my smaller laptop monitor, there seems to be the panel's width reserved in space (which is just empty)

How can I make it reserve space on the right monitor?

My setup looks like this (generated with arandr and modified (`right-of` and `primary` are by me, trying to solve the problem):

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output HDMI1 --primary --right-of LVDS1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1440x0 --rotate normal \
--output LVDS1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 0x368 --rotate normal \
--output TV1 --off --output VGA1 --off
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking into this problem, unfortunately this appears to be (a long standing) bug in xfce: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9693. Also see my thread on the xfce forums that describe the same issue: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8802

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed it!

I went to panel->panel settings->Unchecked "Lock panel". Now grepped the panel from outer right side (with the dots). I moved the panel up and forced it down again. This last step will cause the xfce panel to be recognized again as a bottom panel, meaning it will stay up front whenever I maximize a window.

You can now "Lock the panel" again within the settings. And exit the settings windows.

Answer (score 0):

I usually workaround the problem by setting the resolution of the external monitor again.

xrandr output:

```
xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1440     60.00 +  59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95
...
HDMI-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  60.00    50.00    59.94
   1680x1050     59.88
```

I change the monitor to a lower resolution (mode) then set it back:

`xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode 1680x1050`

then

`xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode 1920x1080`